# __str__(self) in django tutorial returns object instead of text

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm going through the Django tutorials, but I'm having issues using the `__str__(self)`.

When I add the method below in my model:

```
def _str_(self):
        return self.question_text
```

And the run the command: `Question.objects.all()`

It returns something like:

```
<Question: Question object>
```

But what I expect it to return is the actual question text.

Comment: `'_str_' != '__str__'`

Comment: is `self.question_text` a foreign key field by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27188394/296974#comment42863209_27188394).

```
def _str_(self):
    return self.question_text
```

should be

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text
```

with two underscores in left side and two in right side

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a twofold problem. First, like mentioned, `__str__` should use double underscores.

The second issue is that printing out an object on the command line doesn't invoke the `__str__` method. Instead, it uses the `__repr__` method to get a string representation of the object. This is different from the `__str__` method in that it provides a more technical representation of the object, often including the class name and some attributes that uniquely identify the object (id, memory address etc). This is used e.g. in a traceback to better identify the problem.

To get the question text, you'll have to explicitly invoke the `__str__` method, either by calling it directly or by using the `str(object)` method. Note that calling `str()` on a list of model objects will invoke the `__str__` method of the list, and this will in turn still call the `__repr__` method on the objects in the list.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me and it was because the shell needed to be closed and reopened before it registered the addition of the **str** method.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to write this method in the same class where you are defining models method

```
def __str__(self):

    return self.question_text
```